# Nearest points for each row in panda's data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got a CSV file with X, Y, and Z coordinates. I need to add two columns: `R` and `NereastIdx` where `R` stands for the distance to the nearest point (row) and `NereastIdx` is row number of that point. Each row is a unique point.

I am trying to find an efficient way to do this. In my first attempt (using pandas), I have iterated over all rows in for loop, calculated all distances, calculated Min value, checked index, and assigned values for two new columns. But it was TERRIBLY slow. I have googled that KDTree might be useful, but honestly I don't know how to use this for my particular case...

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Please share a sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this (import your data into numpy array first, or use `.to_numpy()` from pandas data frame):

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

pts_nn = np.hstack((pts, np.stack(KDTree(pts).query(pts, k=2))[:,:,1].T))
```

Where `pts` is a `Nx3` array of point (it can actually be any dimension points). The 4-th column is distances to nearest neighbor and 5-th column index of nearest neighbor row.

sample code:

```
N = 10
pts = np.random.random((N, 3))


pts_nn:
                                   distance to   nearest
                                     nearest     neighbor
      X           Y          Z       neighbor    index
      |           |          |          |         |
      v           v          v          v         v

[[0.36154214 0.11883743 0.04484198 0.15207073 6.        ]
 [0.26106654 0.25574324 0.45306327 0.20522814 4.        ]
 [0.15989573 0.55955844 0.63199334 0.35385276 8.        ]
 [0.21143747 0.47216402 0.11990295 0.22398747 5.        ]
 [0.10244485 0.12636136 0.43829583 0.20522814 1.        ]
 [0.0101051  0.41025922 0.19608337 0.13800542 8.        ]
 [0.24196598 0.03731428 0.09154342 0.15207073 0.        ]
 [0.78249018 0.81468931 0.21105137 0.11227299 9.        ]
 [0.06798827 0.41764963 0.32114501 0.13800542 5.        ]
 [0.86526876 0.74024578 0.22558034 0.11227299 7.        ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out implementation of Nearest Neighbors graph, like in `sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph`. What you're trying to do is kind of the same, so look at the library implementation.
You can find more about it:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#unsupervised-neighbors
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph.html#sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph